# how to echo a space at the end without redundant quotes in one particular scenario?

Tags: bash

Consider the following bash transcript:

```
~$ x="echo -n abc "

~$ $x && echo xyz
abcxyz

~$
```

Out of curiosity (please indulge me), I want to have a bash variable containing the `echo -n` command outputting something. I want to know if it is possible to define it in a way to preserve the trailing space.

An obvious option is use the quotes:

```
~$ x="echo -n \"abc \""

~$ $x && echo xyz
"abc "xyz

~$
```

But these quotes pollute the output.

Of course, I can prepend the space to the second echo command:

```
~$ x="echo -n abc "

~$ $x && echo " xyz"
abc xyz

~$
```

But the purpose of the question is to understand if `x` can be changed in a way that `$x` represents `echo -n` with the trailing space without redundant quotes in the output.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is suffering from [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

The solution is to use an array:

```bash
$ x=(echo -n "abc ")
$ "${x[@]}" && echo xyz
abc xyz
```

Comment: Excellent, as expected I learned something new.